# Pandas from_dict multiindex not recognized on index orient

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, multi-index

Suppose I have a dict:

```
input_dict ={('row_1','row_1_1'): [1],
             ('row_1','row_1_2'): [2],
             ('row_2','row_2_1'): [3]}
```

and I want to use the `from_dict` method to convert the input_dict to multiIndex pandas DataFrame.

How can I get it using **orient='index'**?

the expected output should be:

```
                0
row_1   row_1_1 1
        row_1_2 2
row_2   row_2_1 3
```

- With the setting **orient='columns'** columns construct a multiIndex but output is not as expected.

  `type(pd.DataFrame.from_dict(input_dict,orient='columns').columns)`

  the result is:

  `pandas.core.indexes.multi.MultiIndex`
- With the setting **orient='index'**

  `type(pd.DataFrame.from_dict(input_dict,orient='index').index)`

  The result is

  `pandas.core.indexes.base.Index`

I could achieve the conversion with 
`pd.DataFrame.from_dict(input_dict,orient='columns').T` but it is not a clean solution.

Comment: Not very elegant but you could try `pd.DataFrame.from_dict(input_dict, orient='index').set_index(pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(input_dict))` ...